# Replacing text at end of string via command line based on beginning of string

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Given the below json example - how would I replace the 7 characters with a different string after the hash for module2 from a unix command line?

```
{
 "module": "git+https://9gke37d40a7a9f84659e98f386d4ea2fda2a5d86:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org-name/repo.git#71e84fd",
 "module2": "git+https://9gke37d40a7a9f9999e98f386d4ea2fda2a5d86:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org-name/repo.git#99h43ae",
 "module3": "git+https://9gke37d40a7a9f33759e98f386d4ea2fda2a5d6:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org-name/repo.git#94i53bb"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the above lines, you could do

```
sed -i -e 's/(.*module2.*?#)(.......)(.*)/\1abcdefg\3/' json-file
```

where abcdefg would be your replacement string.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to take it a step further how would I insert what was in the system clipboard as the 1abcdefg string?

Comment: Hmm. The shell would not know about the clipboard content. The terminal does.